# Teradata: expected something like ',' between an integer and the word

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I'm trying to create a table and I get the error. Could someone please let me know how to add a column which has an integer starting in its name. Find below the statement and error

```
Create table mutablecode
(
    4th_Procedure_Code varchar(20)
);
```

> Syntax error, expected something like ','

between an integer and the word 'th_Procedure_Code'

Answer (score 0):

A valid object name in Teradata consists of `a-z,A-Z,0-9,#,_,$` but must not start with a digit.

If you really need this column name you must double quote it (then almost any character is allowed):

```
"4th_Procedure_Code" varchar(20)
```

Remark: According to Standard SQL a double quoted name is case-sensitive, but in Teradata it's still case-insensitive.